# audio conference with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, vert.x

i would like build an only-audio conference system based on webrtc for a game, but i must avoid lag.
for example i can use https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection
How many clients can be connected in the same time?and about bandwidth?
I think that the upload will be a limit increasing the amount of connected client.
Could i make a Tree of clients, so each client have only 2 or 3 connections?

The server can be in any language because i will use vert.x
regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two scenarios:**

---

**1: Peer-to-Peer**

In this model; maximum peer connections limit per page on chromium is [256](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/).

**2: Peer-to-Server**

In this model; you can use media server to relay stream over unlimited peers.

---

**In 1st model**; you can face bandwidth/cpu [usage issue](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/RTP-usage.html).

**In 2nd model**; all such things are handled by the media server.

---

If you're planning to setup **peer-to-peer** video-conferencing; you'll use **mesh** model. It is suggested to limit conferencing to **5** users only. Otherwise, you'll face issues like audio-lost, echo and obviously bandwidth/cpu huge usage!

---

In broadcasting p2p scenarios; you can relay i.e. [forward remote streams](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/remote-media-stream-attachment/) to overcome burden from single peer.